# How do I create an XML file with php and have it prompt to download?

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm using domdocument to create an xml file:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

When I click the link to this file, it simply displays it as an xml file. How do I prompt to download instead? Furthermore, how can I prompt to download it as 'backup_11_7_09.xml' (insert todays date and put it as xml) instead of the php file's real name which is 'backup.php'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the `Content-Disposition` header as an attachment prior to your echo:

```
<?  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=myfile.xml'); ?>
```

Of course, you can format `myfile.xml` using [`strftime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) to get a formatted date in the file name:

```
<?
    $name = strftime('backup_%m_%d_%Y.xml');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $name);
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');

    echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=dom.xml');
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header('Pragma: private');
header('Cache-control: private, must-revalidate');

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

If your using a session, use the following settings to prevent problems with IE6:

```
session_cache_limiter("must-revalidate");
session_start();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: text/xml');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my xml file.xml"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('saved.xml'); // or otherwise print your xml to the response stream
?>
```

Use the content-disposition header.

Comment: Copying code from the PHP docs is all well and good, but you could have at least changed it to be relevant to XML.