# Export XML from form data

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm trying to come up with a general routine for exporting form data to an XML format. The goal would be to make it general enough that the form element IDs would serve as the XML nodes, and the form values would obviously be the node content. Here's what I have so far:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
 $doc->formatOutput = true;
 $post = $_POST;
 unset($post['submit']);
 $data = array_values($post);
 $headers = array_keys($post);
 /* TODO - wrap next two lines with if clause */
 /* to check for existing root node */
 $root = $doc->createElement('student');
 $root = $doc->appendChild($root);

 for ($i = 0; count($headers) - 1; $i++)    {
    /* Create and append node for each form element to root */
    $theNode = $doc->createElement($headers[$i]);
    $theNode = $root->appendChild($theNode);

    /* Add content to node */
    $theValue = $doc->createTextNode($data[$i]);
    $theValue = $theNode->appendChild($theValue);
 }
 $fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("Can't open the XML file.");
 fwrite($fh, $doc->saveXML());
 fclose($fh);
 header('Location: thanks.php'); 
}
```

And, as requested, here's the form code, although I think that's irrelevant:

```
          <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
        <p>
          <label for="name">Name: </label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your full name" autofocus required>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="email">Email: </label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="cell">Cell: </label>
          <input type="tel" name="cell" id="cell">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="dob">Date of birth: </label>
          <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="study">Years of art study: </label>
          0 <input type="range" name="study" id="study" min="0" max="16"> 16
        </p>
        <p style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
      </form>
```

Unfortunately, this code results with an HTTP Error 500. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Oh, and as the TODO notes, I need to also figure out if there already is data (a root node exists) in the file, just append and don't reinsert the root node. How do I test for a root node in an XML file?

Thanks so much for your help - Joe

Comment: What line from that code throws the HTTP 500 error? Can you had your form code? That would help us help you.

Comment: Added form code, although I don't think it should make a difference. So far, it looks like the problem (or more likely, the first problem) is in:
$theNode = $doc->createElement($headers[$i]);

Comment: A *500 Internal Sever Error* is ***always*** an invitation to look into the servers error log. It contains more information. As this is PHP, it's also highly likely that it is because of a *Fatal Error in PHP*, so ensuring that PHP error logging is enabled and looking into the PHP error log is very useful, too. [More about the 500 Internal Server Error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13940190/367456)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a 500 Internal Sever Error without showing the relevant log-files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code snippet that'll solve the 1st part of your problem. I added a hard-coded `$_POST` with dummy values to simulate your form submission:

```
<?php
$_POST = array(
    'submit' => true,
    'name'   => 'Name',
    'email'  => 'Email',
    'cell'   => 'Cell',
    'dob'    => 'Date of birth',
    'study'  => 'Years of art study'
);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $doc               = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $doc->formatOutput = true;
    $root              = $doc->createElement('student');
    $root              = $doc->appendChild($root);

    $post = $_POST;
    unset($post['submit']);

    foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
        $node = $doc->createElement($key, $value);
        $root->appendChild($node);
    }

    echo $doc->saveXML();
}
```

#### Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<student>
  <name>Name</name>
  <email>Email</email>
  <cell>Cell</cell>
  <dob>Date of birth</dob>
  <study>Years of art study</study>
</student>
```

For the 2nd part of your problem, the [DOMDocument::saveXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) function doesn't prompt you to download a file or saves a file to disk, instead as its description states:

> DOMDocument::saveXML — Dumps the internal XML tree back into a string

Assuming you want to be able to download the resulting XML take a look at the answer to this question here in SO: [How do I create an XML file with php and have it prompt to download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693806/how-do-i-create-an-xml-file-with-php-and-have-it-prompt-to-download).

Comment: Yup that did it - thanks! I've edited the entry to show how to write out the file. Still looking to solve that TODO problem - seems like it might be in simplexml(); still looking.